# Which font can I use insead of 'Roman 12cpi' in Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using JasperReport 3.7.1
I want to print report in plain text, which font can I use?

I would like to print the report on a dot matrix printer.
I need a font that is the same as 'Roman 12cpi';
because 'Roman 12cpi' is not supported in ireport 3.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by 'plain-text'?

If you really mean plain text (.txt file, no images), than you should export your report using [JRTextExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRTextExporter.html) or [JRCsvExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRCsvExporter.html). In that case, it doesn't matter which font you use. (Note that JasperReports is a poor choice if you only need this kind of reports)

If you only want it to *look* like plain text, you can use other 'plain text looking' fonts, like 'Courier New'

Answer (score 0):

JasperReports supports TrueType fonts and not the Windows "printer-only" fonts that are commonly supplied with dot matrix printer software, such as `Roman 12cpi`.

You'll have more luck exporting your report as pure text(as was suggested by yshalbar) and sending raw escape codes to the printer such as ones in [ESC/P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESC/P) to change your font.

Also, take a look in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449777/print-on-dot-matrix-printer-in-net/449844#449844), for more guidance on printing to dot matrix printers.